# Mising template error with RSPec and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, rspec2

After migrate on Rails 3 some RSpec test broken

Example:

**Controller:**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:note])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @profile.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js do
          render(:update) do |page|
            page.flash.show @profile.errors.full_messages.join(', ')
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Spec:**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ProfilesController do
  before(:each) { sign_in mock_model(Account).as_null_object }

  context 'POST create' do
    it 'is accessible for logged in user' do
      controller.should_receive(:create)
      post :create
    end
  end

end
```

**Got failure:**

```
  19) ProfilesController POST create is accessible for logged in user
     Failure/Error: post :create
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template profiles/create with {:locale=>[:en, :en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:rjs, :rhtml, :rxml, :builder, :erb]} in view paths "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0x1059d48f0>"
     # ./spec/controllers/profiles_controller_spec.rb:48
```

Comment: Do you have render_views turned on? Check your rspec config, too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your controller code?
May be you are really haven't any redirection actions in profiles_controller#create.

something like this:

```
def create
 ...
 redirect_to '/'
end
```